# iOS Bluetooth external accessory - Is it possible to disable the notification on connection?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

We have an accessory based on the Roving Networks RN41 bluetooth module. We have the MFi chip, and the device works OK (only OK).

Whenever the user comes in range of the device, they get an iOS pop-up notification of "APP NAME would like to use DEVICE NAME".

This is really annoying for our users, as with our use-case, they might expect to see this 5-10 times a day.

Is there any way to disable this notification? I have tried removing the registerForLocalNotifications  method, but this has no effect.